# what is the alternative for dynamic class loading in java?

Tags: java, reflection, cglib, byte-buddy

I'm using reflection to load the class at run-time but sonar rules are pointing 
it as vulnerability attack i'm thinking to use ByteBuddy,can bytebuddy library help me on this?

```
ClassLoader classLoader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
Class<?> classsName = classLoader.loadClass(className);
```

Comment: There is no reflection in your above example, just dynamic classloading. And your second line doesn't make sense (`className  = loadClass(className)`) - but perhaps Sonar is complaining that you are getting `className` from an unsafe source. Bytebuddy won't help - you still need to load the class dynamically.

Comment: from the loaded class just i want to make one method accessible to public and i want to invoke.

Comment: methodCall.setAccessible(true);
     methodCall.invoke(getmethod, "text");

Comment: If it’s in the same ClassLoader as a known class (MyClass), why do you need to load it dynamically?  I suspect you can accomplish your goal without a dynamically built class name.

Comment: To demonstrate i have given as MyClass but i need to load different class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will prevent Sonar alert but I'd rather use [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) since it will proceed all the class initialisations that could be required:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
```

Note that this method is overloaded so you can specify a class loader or whether the class needs to be initialized.